# Navbar dropdown menu won't work if table present Bootstrap

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, navbar, bootstrap-table

I am experiencing some problems with bootstrap.

I have a simple HTML web page, with a navigation bar with some dropdown menu buttons. I noticed that the same code I am using in other pages won't work if a table is present in the body. 
I believe there is something wrong in how I structure the tables, though, but I didn't manage to figure it out since I used the standard one, and I fill it with data using javascript.

Here's part of my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title>My Web Page Title</title>

      <style>
        .navbar-nav > li {
          padding-left:10px;
          padding-right:10px;
        }

        #mytable tr:hover {
          background-color:#F2F0F0;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <div class="container p-2">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="btnOne" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ButtonOne</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DropdownOne</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DropdownTwo</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="famBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ButtonTwo</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DropdownOne</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DropdownTwo</a>
```

....all closings tag, and below, always in the body tag:

```
<div class="container pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h3>Table Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Right Table Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterData()" placeholder="Search by name.." title="Type in a name">
  <div class="table">
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-hover">
      <!-- Here goes our data, I fill it dinamically with javascript -->
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

<!-- some omitted Firebase scripts -->

<script src="../main.js"></script>
```

I hope the code is readable enough. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bootstrap 4 dropdown menu requires bootstrap.min.js. Make sure you have linked bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Ok thanks, now the dropdown works, so I am gonna mark this one as correct, but another problem arose: now when I reduce the screen the two buttons disappear, while before they transformed into a hamburger button; it actually had some problems, since it blinked and closed immediately after clicking, but it was nice to know that they were still someway there

Comment: I saw it now. you had linked those scripts inside head tags. I recommend to use them at the end of body tags. I am a beginner. I don't know to explain that. But adding those scripts in the head sometimes produces unexpected behaviors. So try it adding those in the bottom of body tag

Comment: Thank you, you're right! I put them down at the end of the body tag, and the hamburger button is back; for whoever else is reading, I also noticed that when I was keeping both sources of bootstra.min.js (the version I inserted 3.4.1 and EDP's 4.0.0), the hamburger button still had that weird blinking behavior, but now that I removed the oldest one everything is finally working nice.

Comment: Glad to hear that.  I read about that error. As I understood it when the webpage loads it is read from top to bottom by the browser. If you have attached js files at the top browser render them before adding the DOM element. so, action listeners, can't find the DOM elements. They might behave weirdly. So add js files after adding HTML body so js functions can find correct DOM elements.

This is what I understand. I hope someone will correct this if anything wrong here.